# receiving comma separated bytes from python sockets udp

Tags: python, arrays, sockets, udp

I am working with python 3.7.4 trying to use data I am receiving via udp using python sockets. I need the data in an array. Everything I have tried either gives error or changes the data making it useless.

```
import socket
import select

sockets = []

for port in range(5201,5202):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))
    sockets.append(server_socket)

empty = []
while True:
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(sockets, empty, empty)
    for s in readable:
         (client_data, client_address) = s.recvfrom(1024)
         rport=(s.getsockname()[1])
         print (client_data)

for s in sockets:
   s.close()
```

The output is:

b'[255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255]'

I am trying to get this data into an array so I can select individual bytes like client_data[2].

Comment: This is a bad approach but you can try. ```array = eval(output.decode('utf-8'))```. where output is your output ```b'[255,255, ...```

Comment: Can you change the client sending the data?  There are better ways to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately no its closed source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format is basically JSON:

```
>>> s = b'[255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255]'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(s)
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
>>> a = json.loads(s)
>>> a[0]
255
>>> len(a)
128
```